# Input numeric values in Equation Shiny UI

Tags: r, shiny

I have a linear equation: `x = a*21 + b*13 + c*5`.
I need the users to put the values of a , b , c in the Shiny UI and then the server code will return 1/(1 -x). I have got some idea about text inputs from here https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/textInput.html , but I am not getting any references for my problem really.

Can anyone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: My question is, how to achieve this on Shiny. Getting the users to put numeric values in the UI and have 1/(1-x) computed. Thanks.

Comment: There are many tutorials online. Please show your input - post your code and we're happy to help improving it

Comment: My input is only this - x = a*21 + b*13 + c*5. And for thr code , I have tried with sliderInput() and numericInput(), but both gives a y range. I need specific values , and couldnt find any refeences on that.

Answer (score 1):

`shiny::numericInput()` returns a single number input value, not a range.